# Scaling div elements relative to each other from carousel pie highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to display various charts on a bootstrap's carousel. The problem is when I change to the second item of the carousel it's not displayed centered on the div.  Any idea for a workaround?

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/1mo3hwt5/4/][1]
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't show any charts.

Comment: You must have plugin for Chrome (CORS) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: ... Or you could just put the data into the fiddle?

Comment: Plugin CORS chrome is very good work

Comment: Can somehow in such a way:  $('active-item').resize(function(){...}); ?